# Threads and RMI Objects

Tags: java, networking, methods, rmi

In Java RMI, is a new thread started for each new Remote Object that is created?

If so, is this thread a sort of listener thread, who serves incoming invocations by creating a new thread for each method invocation?

I just came up with this mental model, and I 'm looking for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RMI specification neither prescribes nor denies any threading model. When programming the remote part of the program (that which runs in the server) you should assume that the very same object could be accessed by two or more threads at the same time, so you need to synchronize access to mutable fields (even if I think most implementations serialize calls)

Quote from [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html)

> A method dispatched by the RMI runtime to a remote object
>   implementation may or may not execute in a separate thread. The RMI
>   runtime makes no guarantees with respect to mapping remote object
>   invocations to threads. Since remote method invocation on the same
>   remote object may execute concurrently, a remote object implementation
>   needs to make sure its implementation is thread-safe.

Comment: It also doesn't prescribe any specific mapping to listening ports, unless you specify a non-zero port when exporting. You can't therefore assume there is a new listening port per object, or therefore a new listening thread.

Comment: @EJP are you saying the the listening threads can be the same for all the remote objects in the application?

Comment: @GionJh Yes indeed, and if you don't provide non-zero port numbers or socket factories that is exactly what will happen. One port, one listening thread.

Comment: How do I do to provide non-zero port numbers ?

Comment: Via the constructors for `UnicastRemoteObject,` if you're extending it, or the overloads for `exportObject()` if you're not.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to accept your comments as the answer to my question,maybe you can summarize them in a SO answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @GionJh You should accept this one. It is well written, cites the correct part of the correct source, and it answers the question you asked. You turned out to be more interested in ports than threads, but that isn't Raffaele's fault, it's yours, for not making your actual question clear.